# Simple row saving through link with Drupal 7

Tags: views

I have a simple requirement but I am not sure how to fulfill it. On my Drupal site, I need a link which when I click creates a row in a table in DB through AJAX.

That's about it.

The main goal of mine is to create a "My List" for any user. The user can go to any node and press "Save it" and it can then save it to the "List". User can later go to "My List" and see all the "saved" nodes which he saved.

Hence Basically, it's a Save for later for the nodes.

I hope there is some module for it. I couldn't find hence I thought I can create it myself, hence the question.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take a look at the [Favourites module](https://www.drupal.org/project/favorites):

> Favorites provides a tiny block that allows users to easily bookmark
>   any content of the site.

or the [Flag module](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag):

> Flag is a flexible flagging system that is completely customizable by
>   the administrator. Using this module, the site administrator can
>   provide any number of flags for nodes, comments, users, and any other
>   type of entity. Some possibilities include bookmarks, marking
>   important, friends, or flag as offensive. With extensive views
>   integration, you can create custom lists of popular content or keep
>   tabs on important content.

Comment: Thanks a lot Geoff. This provides the much needed assistance. I am grateful.